# docker-compose: no configuration file provided: not found

Tags: docker-compose

I'm trying to dockerize a server-client app 
When running `docker-compose build` it throws `docker-compose build` even though it's right here

I'm working with these versions:
Docker version 25.0.3, build 4debf41
Docker Compose version v2.24.6-desktop.1

[here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DND7t.png)

Comment: dont use images for code; paste code directly